# How to connect cosmosDB using flask-mongoengine

Tags: flask-mongoengine, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I want to access my azure cosmosDB database using flask-mongoengine library.

I've tried to pass host uri in app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] but it's returning empty list from DB collections.

```
db= MongoEngine()
app.config['MONGODB_DB'] = 'DB_NAME'
app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@host:port/?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaSetName'

db.init_app(app)
app.run(port=4001, debug=True)
```

While printing UserModel.objects(username=username) it shows empty list.

P.S. My db has UserModel which store username and passwords of the users.

Comment: No any error occurred?

Comment: No. No errors were shown.

Comment: Could you provide your UserModel + the name of the collection that exist in your server? And eventually one of the record from that collection (anonimyzed)

Comment: Maybe the query is wrong, If you do UserModel.objects(), does it return anything?

Comment: UserModel.objects() returns an empty list.

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by passing the database name in the URI only. I think MongoEngine is unable to parse the DB_NAME from app.config param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by passing the database_name in the URI instead of passing it in app.config

Following worked for me:

`app.config['MONGODB_HOST'] = 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@host:port/DB_NAME?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicaSetName'`

Comment: Thanks for your sharing,you could mark yourself for others' reference.